¿Por qué en una aplicación gráfica con varios clientes a uno se le muestra la interfaz gráfica y a otro no?
Estoy trabajando en una aplicación basada en un servidor centralizado que comunique varios clientes. Los clientes se envían paquetes de información a través del servidor. La aplicación tiene dos interfaces gráficas, el menú de inicio de sesión y el menú principal. La idea es que después de que se introduzcan las credenciales en el menú de inicio de sesión, se mandan al servidor para ser verificadas, y en el caso de ser correctas se permite al cliente iniciar sesión, cerrando el menú de inicio de sesión y abriendo el segundo menú, el principal. Mi problema es que el primer cliente que se conecta al servidor funciona bien, inicia sesión y se abre el segundo menú, pero esto no ocurre en los demás clientes. Al iniciar sesión otro cliente pareciera que el menú principal del primero se recarga, como si se estuviera redibujando pero solo en el primer cliente.
A continuación muestro el fragmento de código correspondiente:
public class HiloCliente
        implements Runnable {

    public HiloCliente() {
        
        Thread HiloCliente = new Thread(this);
        HiloCliente.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
         
            ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket(NetworkDefaults.CLIENT_PORT);
            String mensaje;
            Protocolo paqueteRecibido;

            while (true) {

                Socket miSocket = servidor.accept();

                ObjectInputStream paqueteDatos = new ObjectInputStream(miSocket.getInputStream());
                paqueteRecibido = (Protocolo) paqueteDatos.readObject();

                mensaje = paqueteRecibido.getMensaje();

                miSocket.close();

                //  PROCESAMIENTO DEL PAQUETE SEGÚN LA CABECERA DEL PROTOCOLO  //
                if (mensaje.equals("_startGame")) {
                    Cliente.OcultarInterfazLogin();
                    Cliente.MostrarTablero();    // <- ESTO cuando se conecta el segundo cliente no funciona...

            }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Se ha producido un error de escucha en el servidor...");
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
}

La clase Cliente aparece a continuación:
public class Cliente {

    public static InterfazLogin login = new InterfazLogin();
    public static Tablero tablero = new Tablero();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HiloCliente hiloCliente = new HiloCliente();
        MostrarInterfazLogin();
    }

    public static void MostrarInterfazLogin() {
        login.setVisible(true);
        login.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        login.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void OcultarInterfazLogin() {
        login.setVisible(false);
    }

    public static void MostrarTablero() {
        tablero.setVisible(true);
        tablero.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        tablero.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}

La idea es que cuando el cliente pulse el botón de iniciar sesión en el anterior menú se envíen sus credenciales al servidor, y el servidor después de validar envía un paquete al cliente con el mensaje "_startGame" y en ese momento debería cerrarse el inicio de sesión y abrirse el siguiente menú. Pero lo dicho esto solo ocurre para el primer cliente, y para los sucesivos no.
